# How can I grep a a string with quotes and a regex?

Tags: json, regex, shell, command-line

I have a JSON file that contains a list of files and their sizes. 
I'm trying to **grep** only the line containing the **file size**, which looks like this:

```
"filesize": 10000000
```

I tried single quotes

```
grep -f files.json -o '"filesize":\s[0-9]*'
```

but all I get is this error (once per line):

```
grep: files.json:200: Invalid range end
```

then I tried escaping just the double quotes

```
grep -f files.json -o \"filesize\":\s[0-9]*
```

and I get the same error. The regex code itself seems to be fine because it works in Notepad++ (without the single quotes), I just cannot get it to work in the shell. I tried with bash and zsh.

Edit: solved it with:

```
jq . files.json  | grep -o '"filesize":\s[0-9]*'
```

Comment: If you just do `grep -f files.json -o "filesize"` ? It should return you the whole line

Comment: Or : `grep -f files.json -o 'filesize:\s[0-9]*'` (remove " around file size)

Comment: Don't use line oriented tools for parsing JSON, use a syntax-aware tool like [tag:jq]

Comment: @Chelmy88 I tried both but I get the same error.

Comment: Can you show a part of the file?

Comment: @oguzismail Thank you, that's exactly what I needed, I just piped jq's output to grep and it worked.

Comment: @Chelmy88 I solved it, but thanks for your help! :)

Comment: you don't even need grep if you have jq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-f` flag of `grep` is used to specify a file from which patterns will be read, not the data to work on. The error you're getting is `grep` complaining it fails to parse some data of the file as a pattern.

You could have used the following instead :

```
grep -o '"filesize":\s[0-9]*' files.json
```

As others said it's best to use a tool capable of understanding the syntax of JSON to extract data from a JSON file, but we'd need to see the structure of your data to provide an answer based on one of these tools.